# Read a csv file containing scientific numbers with R

Tags: r, excel, csv, scientific-notation

I am trying to read a csv file containing a column with scientific values.

My csv file looks like this:

[image]

My script code is the following:

```
data <- read.csv('data_physico_qpcr_analyse.csv',sep=";")
head(data)
```

The problem is that the column with the scientific values is formatted as character type and not as numeric.

I have attempted to convert the column with the following syntax:

```
data <- read.csv('data_physico_qpcr_analyse.csv',sep=";",colClasses=c("character","character","numeric","character","character","character",))
```

I have tried to convert the column to numeric in excel as well, but the comma always stays in the format.

How do I convert the cible__par_g column to numeric type using R?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried the following?:

```
options(scipen=999)
```

This usually returns the non-scientific values, but I am not sure if it will help your case when loading in from excel.

Comment: I finally found my mistake, I select the wrong format  on the column  from the csv file, I convert the column to standard and not to scientific. Thank tou for your quick reply !

Comment: That's good that you found out what was wrong and no worries :) The solution I provided anyway will work if R, say, gives you results back in scientific format and you want to convert it back to non-scientific.

Comment: @JulieHardy Selecting "text" is a good idea to prevent names like "April" from turning into dates during Excel import operations.